# javascript sort of HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I'm trying to sort an `li` elements and get an unexpacted result
I need to sort it three times to get it correctly,

where have I mistaken?
javascript

```
var sort_by_name = function(a, b) {
    return a.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > b.innerHTML.toLowerCase();
}
$this = $("ol#table1");
var list = $this.children();
list.sort(sort_by_name);
console.log(list);
$this.html(list);
```

HTML

```
<ol id="table1" style="display: block; ">
   <li class="menu__run">I</li>
   <li class="menu__run">IXX</li>
   <li class="menu__run">I</li>
   <li class="menu__run">I</li>
   <li class="menu__run">I</li>
   <li class="menu__run">I</li>
   <li class="menu__run">I</li>
   <li class="menu__run">I</li> 
   <li class="menu__run">IXX</li>
   <li class="menu__run">I</li>
   <li class="menu__run">I</li>
   <li class="menu__run">I</li>
   <li class="menu__run">I</li>
   <li class="menu__run">I</li>
   <li class="menu__test">st</li>
   <li class="menu__test">st</li>
   <li class="menu__test">st</li>
</ol>
```

[fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Qww87/4/)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There are much better ways to sort.

1. You need a comparison function that returns the right values: -1, 0, and 1.
2. `localeCompare()` is such a comparison function.
3. You can just move the DOM elements around rather than regenerating the HTML.
4. You can get the LI elements directly in the original selector.
5. `"#table1"` is a more efficient selector than `"ol#table1"`.

I would suggest this:

```
$("div#btn").click(function() {
    var sort_by_name = function(a, b) {
        return a.innerHTML.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.innerHTML.toLowerCase());
    }

    var list = $("#table1 > li").get();
    list.sort(sort_by_name);
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        list[i].parentNode.appendChild(list[i]);
    }
});​
```

Which you can see work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/yqd3w/

Comment: can you make something like this for objects under different <div>s?

Comment: @shevski - I'm sure another scenario could be sorted too, but you'd have to show the HTML and describe what you want it sorted by.

Comment: I'll put another question for it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10187186/javascript-sort-of-html-elements-in-place

Comment: You're comparing for human eyes, so you want to ignore all the markup. Rather than `.innerHTML`, you want to compare `.textContent`, which looks at purely the textual data that is presented as visible to the user.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - Yep, it's up to the OP exactly what they want to sort on, but `.textContent` is indeed a good option.

Comment: ""#table1" is a more efficient selector than "ol#table1"." - I don't believe this has ever been the case as browser-vendors have optimized `querySelector` from the start: the runtime performance gains from using `#table1` compared to the _developer_ productivity gains from using `ol#table1` (i.e. not having to remember the element-type of `#table1`) is not a sane trade-off. We're talking literal microseconds difference.

Comment: @Dai - How is `ol#table1` easier to remember than `#table1`?  You've got me baffled there.  I would agree that optimizing the selector efficiency is probably lost in the noise, particularly now in 2020.

Comment: @jfriend00 Because `ol#table1` is self-describing: if we do a `querySelector` we know the result is a `HTMLOLElement` which has a different interface to, say, `HTMLDivElement` or the base `HTMLElement` type. This is relevant if you want to use element-specific features.

Answer (score 8):

A [custom compareFunction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) needs to return -1, 0 or 1.

```
function sort_by_name(a, b) {
    var sa = a.innerHTML.toLowerCase(), sb = b.innerHTML.toLowerCase();
    return sb<sa ? -1 : sb>sa ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var sort_by_name = function(a, b) {
    return $(a).text().toLowerCase().localeCompare($(b).text().toLowerCase());
}
```

You can use localeCompare instead to make things more elegant and workable.

See jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Qww87/11/

Answer (score 2):

according to documentation it needs numeric values.
more intelligible:

```
    var sort_by_name = function(a, b) {
         if(a.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < b.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) return -1;
         if(a.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > b.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) return 1;
         return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use my jquery plugin Sort Content :

```
   $('ol#table1').sortContent({asc:true})
```

That's it!

DEMO :
http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/SjWXU/

Comment: Your repo is no longer available.