# Sort Elements of javascript

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript sort of HTML elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186192/javascript-sort-of-html-elements)

I need to sort a list of elements in this format

```
<table width='a number' bord ...>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      header data
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style='asdasdas' class='asdasdasd' ...>
        rob
      </td
      <td style='asdasdas' class='asdasdasd' ...>
        mike
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style='asdasdas' class='asdasdasd' ...>
        chuck
      </td>
      <td style='asdasdas' class='asdasdasd' ...>
        kev
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

I need to be able to resort the list so people can have the names alphabetical order, I can't understand how to do this

Comment: if you're using jquery, you could use a plugin such as tableSorter or dataTables

Comment: What have you tried? What do you not understand? Have you searched for plugins/code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a plain javascript function that will sort any set of tagged elements:

```
function sortElements(parentId, tagClass) {
    var itemsToSort, p = document.getElementById(parentId);
    if (p.getElementsByClassName) {
        itemsToSort = p.getElementsByClassName(tagClass);
    } else {
        itemsToSort = getElementsByClassName(tagClass, "*", p);
    }
    // get all data into a sortable array
    var data = [], order = [], item, placeHolder, i;
    for (i = 0; i < itemsToSort.length; i++) {
        item = itemsToSort[i];
        // save position of item by inserting a placeholder right before it
        placeHolder = document.createElement(item.tagName);
        item.parentNode.insertBefore(placeHolder, item);
        order.push(placeHolder);
        // save item and text
        data.push({obj: item, text: strTrim(item.innerHTML)});
    }
    // sort the item array by the text
    data.sort(function(a, b) {
        return(a.text.localeCompare(b.text));
    });
    // now reinsert items in sorted order
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        item = data[i].obj;
        placeHolder = order[i];
        // insert in new location
        placeHolder.parentNode.insertBefore(item, placeHolder);
        // remove placeholder
        placeHolder.parentNode.removeChild(placeHolder);
    }
}

function strTrim(str) {
    return(str.replace(/^\s+/, "").replace(/\s+$/, ""));
}

// replacement for older versions of IE
function getElementsByClassName(className, tag, elm){
    var testClass = new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + className + "(\\s|$)");
    var tag = tag || "*";
    var elm = elm || document;
    var elements = (tag == "*" && elm.all)? elm.all : elm.getElementsByTagName(tag);
    var returnElements = [];
    var current;
    var length = elements.length;
    for(var i=0; i<length; i++){
        current = elements[i];
        if(testClass.test(current.className)){
            returnElements.push(current);
        }
    }
    return returnElements;
}
```

​You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/EztNw/.  This demo shows it sorting the OP's table cells and an ordered list just to show that the function works on any set of elements.

The only limitation I'm aware of is that tagged elements cannot be children of other tagged elements.  Works well for cells in a table.

This also uses `getElementsByClassName()` so if older versions of IE are required, then a substitute/shim for that would be added (which is included in the jsFiddle).

Here's how this works:

1. Get a list of all objects you want sorted
2. Put a temporary placeholder object where each item is currently located so we know where to put things back in sorted order
3. Build an array of the objects to be sorted and the sort key (text in this case)
4. Sort that array
5. Reinsert the sorted objects in the now sorted order, using the placeholder as a guide for where they go - remove the placeholder after it's slot is used

​

Comment: Tested in IE7, IE9, Safari, Firefox, Chrome.  Found and fixed a problem in &*^%$ IE.

Comment: thanks, for works perfect now (except I need to do minor changes because of the way mines is structured is a little different)

Comment: hey, i have been testing in IE 8, the line - data.push({obj: item, text: strTrim(item.innerHTML)}); - seems to break the code, can you tell why, (I've tried using innerHTML elsewhere and they work, as well as switching to innerText which won't fix it

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what the issue could be for you.  The jsFiddle I made to demo it works fine in IE8 so perhaps it's something specific to your implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Easy way :

1. **Load names** in a JS array
2. **sort** JS array
3. **Generate and Insert** the table from the array

Answer (score 1):

assuming you want to do this all with only Javascript

```
    var names = ["rob", "mike", "chuck", "kev" };

    names.sort(); //gives you an array with [chuck, kev, mike, rob]
```

Your table as an object

```
    var table = "<table width='a number' bord ...>" +
                   "<tbody>" +
                      "<tr>" +
                        "header data" +
                      "</tr>"
                      "<tr>" +
                        "<td style='asdasdas' class='asdasdasd' ...>" +
                          names[0] +
                        "</td>" +
                        "<td style='asdasdas' class='asdasdasd' ...>" +
                           names[1] +
                        "</td>" +
                      "</tr>" +
                      "<tr>" +
                        "<td style='asdasdas' class='asdasdasd' ...>" +
                          names[2] +
                        "</td>" +
                        "<td style='asdasdas' class='asdasdasd' ...>" +
                          names[3] +
                        "</td>" +
                      "</tr>" +
                    "</tbody>";
```

insert the table object wherever you want. plugins can be bloated and would probably be overkill for something as simple as this. However if you have the option I would recommend doing this server side instead of on the client as this would eliminate the need for cross browser support and ensures that the user cannot disable your shiny new alphabetically sorted table.

Answer (score -1):

I implemented a solution too using jQuery. Take a look:

**HTML:**

```
<table id="dataTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="firstName">
        foo
      </td>
      <td class="lastName">
        bar
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="firstName">
        rob
      </td>
      <td class="lastName">
        mike
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="firstName">
        chuck
      </td>
      <td class="lastName">
        norris
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<input id="sortByFirstName" type="button" value="Sort By First Name"/>
<br/>
<input id="sortByLastName" type="button" value="Sort By Last Name"/>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function sortByCellValue( tableId, sortBy ) {

    var rows = $( "#" + tableId + " tbody tr" );
    var structuredRows = [];

    // extract all row data
    rows.each(function( index, item ) {

        var data = $(item).children().filter("td[class='" + sortBy + "']").html().trim();

        structuredRows.push({
            useToSort: data,
            row: item
        });

    });

    // sorting the rows
    structuredRows.sort(function( a, b ){

        var va = a.useToSort;
        var vb = b.useToSort;

        if ( va < vb ) {
            return -1;
        } else if ( va > vb ) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }

    });

    // cleaning the tbody and inserting the rows in order
    var tBody = $( "#" + tableId + " tbody" );
    tBody.html( "" );

    for ( var i in structuredRows ) {
        tBody.append( structuredRows[i].row );
    }    

}

$(function(){
    $( "#sortByFirstName" ).click( function(){
        sortByCellValue( "dataTable", "firstName" );
    });

    $( "#sortByLastName" ).click( function(){
        sortByCellValue( "dataTable", "lastName" );
    });
});
```

The jsFiddle can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/UTTz8/

Answer (score -2):

I would not want to do this manually as there are plugins available for what you are trying to do. Some of them are proven to be working nice and supported nice. I'd just use [this](http://datatables.net/)

Comment: If the table is dynamically updated, this is a good idea. Otherwise it might just be a big overhead for a simple problem.