# Add Class Name and clicking expand/collapse with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I need some help with JavaScript. I want to add a click function to every node elements in my program and also want to add class name with the help of JavaScript. I mean by click function is that if I click on item it will close and if I again click on item fruits with appear. The following is my JavaScript code, and I am attaching live fiddle to so the program I am working with. Please I want the code with JavaScript not jQuery.

[Live Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/32eVr/7/)

---

```
item
  fruits
     Orange
     Banana
     Mango
```

---

```
function generate(node) {
    if (node.nodeType != 1) return "";
    var html = "<li>" + node.nodeName + " = " + node.childNodes.length;
    var htmlForChildNodes = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
        htmlForChildNodes += generate(node.childNodes[i]);
    }
    if (htmlForChildNodes) {
        html += "<ul>" + htmlForChildNodes + "</ul>";
    }
    html += "</li>";
    return html;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following in case if you wrap your list names with `<a>` elements:

```
// ...
var html = "<li><a href='javascript:;'>" + node.nodeName + "</a>";
// ...

var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0, len = a.length; i < len; i++) {
    a[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        var ul = this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('ul');
        if (ul.length) {
            ul[0].className =
                ul[0].className.indexOf('collapsed') > -1
                    ? ul[0].className.replace('collapsed', '')
                    : ul[0].className + ' collapsed';
        }

        return false;
    }, false);
}
```

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/32eVr/26/

Comment: Thank you very much .It is working great, just wanted to know how can i do sorting of the every Elements

Comment: @user3314588 Sorting of what?

Comment: i sorting of node elemnts if you see in the live fiddle you will see title, author, year, price. just was wondering that how to sort it in author, price, title, year

Comment: @user3314588 That's another question, mate.

Comment: Sir i need some logic so that i can start working with sorting, but i know all the basci knowladge, i mean how should i starty working with sorting in my program

Comment: @user3314588 OK. Check out [array sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method and do sorting before populating the markup with tags.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try to use `var li = document.createElement('li')` and then

```
li.addEventListener('click', function() {
   // Add class here
});
```

Have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/32eVr/30/

This function will generate your `ul` list and when an element is clicked it will get the class `clicked`

```
function generate(node) {
    if (node.nodeType != 1) return null;
    var html = document.createElement("li");
    var text = document.createTextNode(node.nodeName);
    html.addEventListener('click', function() {
       this.className = "clicked";
    });
    html.appendChild(text);
    var htmlForChildNodes = document.createElement("ul");
    for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var child = generate(node.childNodes[i]);
        if(child !== null)
            htmlForChildNodes.appendChild(child);
    }
    html.appendChild(htmlForChildNodes);
    if (htmlForChildNodes.hasChildNodes) {
        return html;
    }
    return null;
}
```

In your CSS you can then a something like

```
li.clicked {
    display: block;
}

/* Hide elements except the top level */
li > ul > li {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Can u please show me how to do it... as i tried that method but was not successful.i have attached live fiddle i am working with

Comment: This is a pure JavaScript solution without having to use jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Here is my proposal:

JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector("ul").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.target.classList.toggle("selected");
});
```

CSS:

```
li.selected ul {
    display: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nsZS8/

Comment: It is working great, just wanted to know how can i do sorting of the every Elements

Comment: There was a question about sorting html elements: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11545960/sort-elements-of-javascript?lq=1

Comment: You should note that classList is a pretty new feature and it might not work for everyone, e.g. < IE10. http://caniuse.com/classlist

Comment: Absolutely agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery to make it easier. Try below,

```
var txt = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><bookstore>    <book category="cooking">        <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>        <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>        <year>2005</year>        <price>30.00</price>    </book>    <book category="children">        <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>        <author>J K. Rowling</author>        <year>2005</year>        <price>29.99</price>    </book>    <book category="web">        <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>        <author>James McGovern</author>        <author>Per Bothner</author>        <author>Kurt Cagle</author>        <author>James Linn</author>        <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>        <year>2003</year>        <price>49.99</price>    </book>    <book category="web" cover="paperback">        <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>        <author>Erik T. Ray</author>        <year>2003</year>        <price>39.95</price>    </book></bookstore>';

function generate(node) {
    if (node.nodeType != 1) return "";
    var html = "<li class='book'>" + node.nodeName;
    var htmlForChildNodes = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
        htmlForChildNodes += generate(node.childNodes[i]);
    }
    if (htmlForChildNodes) {
        html += "<ul>" + htmlForChildNodes + "</ul>";
    }
    html += "</li>";
    return html;
}

if (window.DOMParser) {
    parser = new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(txt, "text/xml");
} else { // Internet Explorer
    xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmlDoc.async = false;
    xmlDoc.loadXML(txt);
}

document.body.innerHTML = "<ul>"+generate(xmlDoc.documentElement)+"</ul>";

$('body').on('click','.book',function(e){
    $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
    e.stopPropogation();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/32eVr/25/)

Comment: Is there anything mentioned about using jQuery?

Comment: @VisioN using jquery is a crime?

Comment: No. But why not give a solution in VBScript then?

Comment: you try that if you can.

Comment: I won't since there is nothing mentioned about VBScript in the question, as well as about jQuery. If you want to propose the OP to use jQuery, then it is worth to mention the suggestion in the answer and replace all pure JS constructions, as `document.body.innerHTML` with better (and faster) jQuery alternatives.

Comment: No Jquery is not a crime, but first i have to do properlearing of Javascript, which is very basic